# Coupon Magento API Soap

Tags: web-services, magento, soap

I’ve a problem with the Coupon API when i make :

```
$couponCode = "test";

$resultCartCoupon = $proxy->call($sessionId, "cart_coupon.add", array($shoppingCartId, $couponCode));
```

I always got : Uncaught SoapFault exception: [1083] Coupon is not valid if i try the coupon code in the front end there is no problem. Is there anyone who have ever used this API part with success ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes from `Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart_Coupon_Api::_applyCoupon()`

```
if ($couponCode) {
    if (!$couponCode == $quote->getCouponCode()) {
        $this->_fault('coupon_code_is_not_valid');
    }
}
```

This looks like it could be a bug, instead it should be `if ($couponCode != $quote->getCouponCode()) {` but I'm not certain.

It could be that the cart (quote) you're trying to apply the coupon to isn't valid, i.e. doesn't have the qualifying items it needs to receive the coupon.  Are you sure `$shoppingCartId` correctly matches the expected quote in Magento's `sales_flat_quote` table?

Comment: I noticed that the error is in this excerpt:<br>

<code>
try {
            $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
            $quote->setCouponCode(strlen($couponCode) ? $couponCode : '')
                ->collectTotals()
                ->save();

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_fault("cannot_apply_coupon_code", $e->getMessage());
        }
<code>
<br>
Em especifico nesta linha:<code>->collectTotals()<code>

Ao retirar este trecho, não da erro, mas não aplicado o cupom.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the error is in this excerpt:

```
try { 
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true); 
    $quote->setCouponCode(strlen($couponCode) ? $couponCode : '') 
    ->collectTotals() 
    ->save(); 
} catch (Exception $e) { 
    $this->_fault("cannot_apply_coupon_code", $e->getMessage()); 
}
```

In this specific line: `->collectTotals()` By removing this stretch , not of error , but not applied the coupon.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging 2-3 hour on API, I have solved this error at my-end. Check below code which i have used in Coupon API.

```
<?php
 $mage_url = 'http://yoursiteurl/api/soap?wsdl';
 $mage_user= "API_User"; //webservice user login
 $mage_api_key = "API_PASSWORD"; //webservice user pass
 $client = new SoapClient($mage_url);

 $couponCode = 'couponCode'; // a coupon to be apply
 $shoppingCartId = '35'; // a cart Id which i have put test id
 $sessionId = $client->login($mage_user, $mage_api_key);
 $result = $client->call($sessionId,'cart_coupon.add',array($shoppingCartId,$couponCode));

 print_r($result);
?>

The above code gives error that "Uncaught SoapFault exception: [1083] Coupon is not valid". When i debugg the core code i came to know that magento cart.create API insert wrong store id in sales_flat_quote table. I have changed the store id value in sales_flat_quote table manually and again run the Coupon API and after that it works perfectly. So here is the my solution. When you create cart id just run the below update query to change the store id.

<?php
 $shoppingCartId = $soap->call( $sessionId, 'cart.create');

 $mageFilename = '../app/Mage.php';
 require_once $mageFilename;
 umask(0);
 Mage::app();

 $db_write1 = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
 $updateQue  = "update sales_flat_quote set store_id='1' where entity_id ='".$shoppingCartId."'";
 $db_write1->query($updateQue);

 // Now run the Coupon API here
?>
```

Code taken from here : http://chandreshrana.blogspot.in/2015/11/uncaught-soapfault-exception-1083.html

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to write direct SQL to resolve this issue. **Just specify store ID parameter in the API call**. Example is below is the demo script to apply discount code using Magento SOAP APIs V2 :

```
/* Set Discount Code */

try
{
    $result = $client->shoppingCartCouponAdd($session, $quoteId, 'test123',$storeId);
    echo "<br>Apply discount code: ";
    var_dump($result);
}
catch(Exception $ex)
{
    echo "<br>Discount code Failed: " . $ex->getMessage();
}
```

To apply discount code, perform following steps :

```
$quoteId = $client->shoppingCartCreate($session,$storeId);

/* Set cart customer */
$guest = true;

if ($guest) 
{
    $customerData = array(
        "firstname" => "testFirstname",
        "lastname" => "testLastName",
        "email" => "testEmail@mail.com",
        "mode" => "guest",
        "website_id" => "1"
    );
} 
else 
{
    $customer  = array(
        "customer_id" => '69301',
        "website_id" => "1",
        "group_id" => "1",
        "store_id" => "1",
        "mode" => "customer",
    );
}

//Set cart customer (assign customer to quote)
$resultCustomerSet = $client->shoppingCartCustomerSet($session, $quoteId, $customerData,$storeId);

/* Set customer addresses Shipping and Billing */

$addresses = array(
    array(
        "mode" => "shipping",
        "firstname" => "Ahsan",
        "lastname" => "testLastname",
        "company" => "testCompany",
        "street" => "testStreet",
        "city" => "Karachi",
        "region" => "Sindh",
        "postcode" => "7502",
        "country_id" => "PK",
        "telephone" => "0123456789",
        "fax" => "0123456789",
        "is_default_shipping" => 0,
        "is_default_billing" => 0
    ),
    array(
        "mode" => "billing",
        "firstname" => "Ahsan",
        "lastname" => "testLastname",
        "company" => "testCompany",
        "street" => "testStreet",
        "city" => "Karachi",
        "region" => "Sindh",
        "postcode" => "7502",
        "country_id" => "PK",
        "telephone" => "0123456789",
        "fax" => "0123456789",
        "is_default_shipping" => 0,
        "is_default_billing" => 0
    )
);

//Set cart customer address
$resultCustomerAddress = $client->shoppingCartCustomerAddresses($session, $quoteId, $addresses,$storeId);   

/* Set payment method */
$responsePayment = $client->shoppingCartPaymentMethod($session, $quoteId,       array(
    'method' => 'cashondelivery',
),$storeId);  

/* Set shipping method */
$setShipping = $client->shoppingCartShippingMethod($session, $quoteId, 'flatrate_flatrate',$storeId);
```

After all above apply discount code,

```
try
{
    $result = $client->shoppingCartCouponAdd($session, $quoteId, 'test123',$storeId);
    echo "<br>Apply discount code: ";
    var_dump($result);
}
catch(Exception $ex)
{
    echo "<br>Discount code Failed: " . $ex->getMessage();
}
```